# Does SQLite have a C++ object-oriented interface?

Tags: c++, sqlite

SQLite comes with a C-style interface, where you need to explicitly close every resource (no destructors).

```
int rc = sqlite3_open16(databaseFileName, &sqlite->db);
...
sqlite3_close(_sqlite->db);
```

Is there a C++ interface or a wrapper around the C-style interface available, which would add destructors, like [gtkmm](http://www.gtkmm.org/en/) is to GTK+? Something like:

```
class SQLiteDb
{
public:
    SQLiteDb() {
        int rc = sqlite3_open16(databaseFileName, &db);
        if(rc != SQLITE_OK){
            std::string errorText = sqlite3_errmsg(db);
            throw std::runtime_error(errorText);
        }
    }
    ~SQLiteDb() {
        sqlite3_close(db);
    }
private:
    sqlite3 *db;
};
```

Comment: If all you need is SBRM `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` both allow you to supply a custom "deleter".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Searching for "SQLite RAII" on your search engine of choice finds [this library](http://srombauts.github.io/SQLiteCpp/).

Comment: I did search with Google, but obviously your Google-fu is better than my Google-fu :) Thanks!